# DateTime format in DataGridView currentRow add years

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to display Expired date.(PurchaseDate + 3 years)

In this case, how can I add 3 years into txtExipredDate Textbox.

Would you give me the feedback? Thanks.

```
setExpired.txtPurchaseDate.Text = dgvRentalList.CurrentRow.Cells[11].Value.ToString();

//Below, I want to Add 3 years
setExpired.txtExpiredDate.Text = dgvRentalList.CurrentRow.Cells[11].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: what is the type of `dgvRentalList.CurrentRow.Cells[11].Value`?

Comment: That is DateTime format.

Comment: Then my current answer should work

Comment: @wholee1, i added my answer below view it might be it help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to convert value contains in `dgvRentalList.CurrentRow.Cells[11].Value` to `DateTime` because its return object and then bind it to textbox like

```
setExpired.txtPurchaseDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(dgvRentalList.CurrentRow.Cells[11].Value).AddYears(3).ToString();
```

**OR**

```
var cellValue = dgvRentalList.CurrentRow.Cells[11].Value;
setExpired.txtPurchaseDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(cellValue).AddYears(3).ToString();
```

You can use any date time format like `.AddYears(3).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");` to display date in your textbox.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Convert to datetime the date and try: DateTime.AddYears(number_of_years_to_add);

Good luck !!!

Answer (score 0):

If typeof `dgvRentalList.CurrentRow.Cells[11].Value`  is DateTime, you can simply add 3 years to it using `DateTime.AddYears()`:

```
setExpired.txtExpiredDate.Text = dgvRentalList.CurrentRow.Cells[11].Value.AddYears(3).ToString();
```

Comment: Actually, dgvRentalList.CurrentRow.Cells[11].Value.AddYears(3).ToString();
is not working.. after Cells[11].Value, AddYear selection is not appear.

Comment: well the obviously it is not `DateTime` and may be a string reperesenting the datetime?

Comment: if you could show what is the current value being set, I might be able to help better

Comment: You may log its type like this:  `dgvRentalList.CurrentRow.Cells[11].Value.GetType().ToString()`

Comment: `.GetType()` would return the data type, I want to know what is its datata type, for example if it is a string like: `2018-11-18`, then you may use `DateTime.ParseExact(dgvRentalList.CurrentRow.Cells[11].Value, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.CultureInvariant).AddYears(3).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");`